# Got error from AudioUnitRender() function

Tags: iphone

I want to implement the I/O with a Render Callback Function Pattern in the "Audio Unit Hosting Guide for iOS" document. I'm not sure how to implement the render callback function.

My parts of codes are listed below:

```
- (void) configureAndInitializeAudioProcessingGraph {
...
NSLog (@"- Attach the input render callback and context to the input bus");

AURenderCallbackStruct inputCallbackStruct;
inputCallbackStruct.inputProc        = &inputRenderCallback;
inputCallbackStruct.inputProcRefCon  = NULL;    //&soundData;                   

result = AUGraphSetNodeInputCallback (
                                       processingGraph, 
                                       ioNode, 
                                       0,          //output element of I/O unit     
                                       &inputCallbackStruct
                                       );
...
}


static OSStatus inputRenderCallback (
void                        *inRefCon,      
AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  *ioActionFlags,
const AudioTimeStamp        *inTimeStamp,
UInt32                      inBusNumber,   
UInt32                      inNumberFrames,
AudioBufferList             *ioData 
) 
{

DCIDBAudio *audio = (DCIDBAudio *)inRefCon;

OSStatus err = AudioUnitRender (
            audio.ioUnit, 
            ioActionFlags, 
            inTimeStamp, 
            1,            input element od I/O unit
            inNumberFrames, 
            ioData
            );

if (err)
{
    NSLog(@"AudioUnitRender() failed.");
    return err;
}

return noErr;

}
```

I always get the error "AudioUnitRender() failed." I just want to use AudioUnitRender() to get data from the output of the 1 element of the io unit and then put the data into the ioData buffer so that they cab be used by the 0 element of the io unit.

Could anybody point out what's wrong in my above codes? should I initialize the parameters:
inNumberFrames and ioData first?

Any comments and instructions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Finspoo

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer because i'm issuing kind of same problems but you could digg what's done in the [mixerhost](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MixerHost/Introduction/Intro.html) apple demo app

Answer (score 0):

It'd help to know the OSStatus err code to try to determine what step you missed.  Also, you should post all code relevant to initializing `audio.ioUnit`.

Make sure you've enabled IO on the input bus of your unit, such as:

```
UInt32 enableInput = 1;
AudioUnitSetProperty( ioUnit, kAudioOutputUnitProperty_EnableIO, kAudioUnitScope_Input, AudioUnitBus::Input, &enableInput, sizeof(enableInput) );
```